# ViewPager swipe inside recyclerView not working

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-viewpager

I built a simple ImageViewPager and I've putted it in the recyclerView's item but it seems to be not working, am I missing something?.
another problem is my recyclerview drag is horizontal and the viewPager's drag is horizontal too. is there a way to coordinate between them?

Here is my viewPager class -

```
public class ImageViewPager extends ViewPager {


public ImageViewPager(@NonNull Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public ImageViewPager(@NonNull Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public void setUrls(List<String> urls){
    setAdapter(new ImagePagerAdapter(urls,getContext()));
}



private static class ImagePagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter{
    private List<String> urls;
    private Context context;

    public ImagePagerAdapter(List<String> urls, Context context) {
        this.urls = urls;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return urls.size();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(@NonNull View view, @NonNull Object object) {
        return view.equals(object);
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(@NonNull ViewGroup container, int position, @NonNull Object object) {
        container.removeView((View) object);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(@NonNull ViewGroup container, int position) {
        String photoUrl = urls.get(position);
        View  view = LayoutInflater.from(container.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.image_view_pager_lay,container,false);
        ImageView imageView = view.findViewById(R.id.image_ImagePagerView);
        Picasso.with(container.getContext()).load(photoUrl).fit().into(imageView);
        container.addView(view,0);
        return view;
    }
}
```

}